# Using usort() to sort a 2-dimensional array with hierarchical ordering criteria

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to sort an 2-dimensional array of pizza toppings by the category of topping it belongs to. But the way the client supplies the data isn't ideal for this. Here's a sample of the data:

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 30
                [title] => Pepperoni
                [meat] => 1
                [veggie] => 
                [sauce] => 
                [cheese] => 
                [condiment] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 29
                [title] => Onions
                [meat] => 
                [veggie] => 1
                [sauce] => 
                [cheese] => 
                [condiment] => 
            )
```

The idea is that the toppings should always be grouped by a type (ie. `meat`) in a specific order (ie. `meats` followed by `veggies` followed by `sauces` and so on)—independent of the order in which they're retrieved. Importantly, no topping ever belongs to two types.

Here's my stab at this:

```
$topping_options = array()  // ie. the sample data above
usort($topping_options,
                function($opt_a, $opt_b) {
                    $scores = array("a" =>  0, "b" => 0);
                    foreach( array("a" => $opt_a, "b" => $opt_b) as $index => $opt) {
                        if ($opt['meat']) $scores[$index] = 5;
                        if ($opt['veggie']) $scores[$index] = 4;
                        if ($opt['sauce']) $scores[$index] = 3;
                        if ($opt['cheese']) $scores[$index] = 2;
                        if ($opt['condiment']) $scores[$index] = 1;
                    }

                    return $scores['a'] - $scores['b'];
                }
            );
```

This doesn't at all achieve my aims and I don't understand why; it seems to me that whenever `$opt_a` has a higher score than `$opt_b` it should keep it's position while `$opt_b` gets sent down a rung for further comparisons. Would like to understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Do elements ever have, say, both 'meat' and 'sauce' set? If so, your `if`s need to be chained into `elseif`s to avoid dropping through to a lower score.

Comment: Good question, but nope, everything is only ever one of these types.

Comment: Could you provide (edit into the question) a short example of input that fails to sort correctly, and the current output? Preferably in a form that can be pasted back into code, e.g. use var_export rather than print_r.

Comment: Was going to do but it's been resolved since, thanks.

Comment: @Jonline: ideally, if you can do that anyway, it leaves the question in a more useful state so that future readers can follow how the accepted answer solves the problem. (There may not be any value in doing so, depending how trivial the solution was - I'll leave that up to you. But this is a good policy in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think that your code is correct and problem in test data. Reorder them  to see result
2. To obtain correct result  order, change code to

   return $scores['b'] - $scores['a'];

Comment: Please explain why this would help.

Comment: Actually, he's exactly right; my function was working fine but in reverse and somehow I just didn't notice that. :S

Comment: @Jonline I was not asking for that because I disagreed, but because a little piece of code with no explanation will not be as useful to anyone who might look at this later.

Comment: Jonline, yes!. I could not write more yesterday - there was no time. And I thought that if you substitute this operator, you will understand that the problem was of test data. but not of the code )

Comment: @splash58: would you add in something now? Remember that answers are not just for the poster, but for future readers as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to approach the situation. I've just separated all of the toppings into their own array and then merged them together at the end:

```
<?php
$toppings = array(
    array('id'=>1,'title'=>'M1','meat'=>1,'veggie'=>NULL,'sauce'=>NULL,'cheese'=>NULL,'condiment'=>NULL),
    array('id'=>2,'title'=>'V1','meat'=>NULL,'veggie'=>1,'sauce'=>NULL,'cheese'=>NULL,'condiment'=>NULL),
    array('id'=>3,'title'=>'M2','meat'=>1,'veggie'=>NULL,'sauce'=>NULL,'cheese'=>NULL,'condiment'=>NULL),
    array('id'=>4,'title'=>'V2','meat'=>NULL,'veggie'=>1,'sauce'=>NULL,'cheese'=>NULL,'condiment'=>NULL),
    array('id'=>5,'title'=>'M3','meat'=>1,'veggie'=>NULL,'sauce'=>NULL,'cheese'=>NULL,'condiment'=>NULL)
);

$categories = array(
    'meat',
    'veggie',
    'sauce',
    'cheese',
    'condiment'
);

$segregated_toppings = array();

foreach($toppings as $topping){

    foreach($categories as $c){
        if($topping[$c]){
            if(!isset($segregated_toppings[$c])){
                $segregated_toppings[$c] = array();
            }

            $segregated_toppings[$c][] = $topping;
        }
    }
}

#echo '<pre>',print_r($segregated_toppings),'</pre>';

$sorted_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$segregated_toppings);

echo '<pre>',print_r($sorted_array),'</pre>';
```